# Вылетает jsoup-парсер веб страниц

Tags: java, android, android-studio, парсер, jsoup

Я сделал парсер веб-страниц для своего андроид приложения, и он нормально работает, но через некоторое время вылетает. Ошибку вызывает блок кода, отвечающий за открытие ссылки и получение URL'а картинки оттуда, и я не могу понять, в чём проблема.

Картинки есть во всех новостях, которые он парсит, но он чем то недоволен. Как решить эту проблему? Код и логи прилагаю ниже:

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

public Elements content;
public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new NewThread().execute();
    new NewThread().execute();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, titleList);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String cleaner(String a){
        String source = a;
        String result = "";
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(source);

        for(String retrival: source.split(" ")){
            arr.add(retrival);

        }

        arr.remove(0);




        Iterator<String> iterator = arr.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            String string = iterator.next();

            if (string.equals("Россия") || string.equals("Екатеринбург")) {
                iterator.remove();

            }else{
                result += string+" ";
            }

        }




        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        Document doc;

        try{
            doc= Jsoup.connect("https://www.znak.com/?&%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5").get();
            content = doc.select(".pub");

            int link_counter = 0;
            titleList.clear();
            for(Element contents: content){
                titleList.add(cleaner(contents.text()));
                String href = doc.getElementsByClass("pub").get(link_counter).attr("href");
              //  Log.d("parse", href); 
                String region = doc.getElementsByClass("region").get(link_counter).text();
              //  Log.d("Title", region);
                String time = doc.getElementsByTag("time").get(link_counter).attr("datetime");
              //  Log.d("Time", time);

//Блок кода ниже вызывает ошибку
                    Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.znak.com"+href).get();
                String pic_url=doc2.getElementsByTag("img").get(link_counter).attr("src"); 
                Log.d("picture", pic_url+" "+contents.text());

                link_counter++;
            }

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

Логи:

```
04-29 14:19:54.849 6443-6443/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-29 14:19:54.861 6443-6443/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
04-29 14:19:55.090 6443-6443/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-29 14:19:55.323 6443-6461/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
04-29 14:19:55.337 6443-6465/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
04-29 14:19:55.370 6443-6465/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
04-29 14:19:55.370 6443-6465/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-29 14:19:55.370 6443-6465/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-29 14:19:55.371 6443-6465/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-29 14:19:55.371 6443-6465/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
04-29 14:19:55.382 6443-6465/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa55af600: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
04-29 14:19:55.407 6443-6465/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa55af600: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xafdaa640)
04-29 14:19:55.452 6443-6465/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa55af600: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xafdaa640)
04-29 14:19:56.102 6443-6448/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=15KB, data=29KB
04-29 14:19:56.105 6443-6448/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=15KB, data=29KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
04-29 14:19:56.934 6443-6461/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/picture: //img.znak.com/logo-200x96.png Екатеринбург Не забыли, понимаешь Музей Ельцина в Екатеринбурге — во всех смыслах удивительное место
04-29 14:19:56.942 6443-6448/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=45KB
    After code cache collection, code=60KB, data=45KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
04-29 14:19:57.690 6443-6461/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/picture: //img.znak.com/1397932.jpg Екатеринбург Музей истории Екатеринбурга ищет «око Саурона» для Водонапорной башни на Плотинке
04-29 14:19:58.229 6443-6461/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/picture: https://img.znak.com/1856629.jpg Екатеринбург В Екатеринбурге музей конструктивизма вынужден отдать часть своих площадей швейному цеху
04-29 14:19:58.673 6443-6461/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/picture:  Екатеринбург Музей Екатеринбурга раскрыл секрет памятника соратнику Ленина, расстрелявшему Николая II
04-29 14:20:01.250 6443-6461/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting, PID: 6443
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting.MainActivity$NewThread.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:117)
        at com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting.MainActivity$NewThread.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:54)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
04-29 14:20:01.578 6443-6465/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa55af600: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xafdaa640)
04-29 14:20:02.211 6443-6472/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/picture: //img.znak.com/logo-200x96.png Екатеринбург Не забыли, понимаешь Музей Ельцина в Екатеринбурге — во всех смыслах удивительное место
04-29 14:20:02.626 6443-6472/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/picture: //img.znak.com/1397932.jpg Екатеринбург Музей истории Екатеринбурга ищет «око Саурона» для Водонапорной башни на Плотинке
04-29 14:20:05.327 6443-6472/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/picture: https://img.znak.com/1856629.jpg Екатеринбург В Екатеринбурге музей конструктивизма вынужден отдать часть своих площадей швейному цеху
04-29 14:20:05.782 6443-6472/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting D/picture:  Екатеринбург Музей Екатеринбурга раскрыл секрет памятника соратнику Ленина, расстрелявшему Николая II
04-29 14:20:08.338 6443-6472/com.example.max.recyclerviewtesting I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6443 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Вы выбираете все картинки из одной страницы новости и пытаетесь взять одну по номеру, как-будто из списка новостей. Нужно что-то вроде `doc2.getElementsByTag("img first").get(0).getElementsByTag("img").get(0).attr("src")`

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо woesss'у, его идея была правильной. Вот как должен работать тот участок кода:

```
String pic_url=doc2.getElementsByTag("img").get(1).attr("src");
```